# Does flask.render_template() create variables with the None keyword assigned to them?

Tags: python, if-statement, flask, boolean

I have 4 files:

flask_blog.py

```
from flask import Flask, render_template

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
@app.route("/home")
def home_page():
    return render_template("home.html")

@app.route("/about")
def about():
    return render_template("about.html", title = "About")
```

layout.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    {% if title %}
        <title>Flask Blog - {{ title }}</title>
    {% else %}
        <title>Flask Blog</title>
    {% endif %}
</head>
<body>
    {% block content %}{% endblock content %}
</body>
</html>
```

home.html

```
{% extends "layout.html" %}

{% block content %}{% endblock content %}
```

about.html

```
{% extends "layout.html" %}

{% block content %}{% endblock content %}
```

On my about page, the title is "Flask Blog - About", and in my home page, the title is "Flask blog". Now, this is happening due to the if/else statements in the layout.html file. The if/else statements are:

```
{% if title %}
    <title>Flask Blog - {{ title }}</title>
{% else %}
    <title>Flask Blog</title>
{% endif %}
```

Now, the value of the 'title' variable must be 0 or None, since we are going to the else statement for the home page. Now, my question is, we didn't assign a value to the 'title' variable beforehand. Better yet, we haven't even created the 'title' variable in the flask_blog.py file. How are we not getting a NameError? Shouldn't we get `NameError: name 'title' is not defined`?

---

[Related](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.2.x/api/#flask.render_template)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The templating language used by default in flask is [Jinja](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.1.x/). Jinja is not Python, and as such it works a little differently sometimes.

When a variable is not defined, `if` statements in Jinja template evaluate to `False`. As a result it doesn't throw an exception but instead it just goes to the next `else` block.

More specifically, an undefined variable becomes of type `Undefined`, which has it's own documentation page: https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.1.x/api/#undefined-types

This is useful in a templating language, because it makes it easier to re-use complex templates without having to specify every parameter every time you render it. If a parameter (and corresponding if block) is not relevant for a call to render_template, you can just omit it and don't worry about it.